# find unique sentences in two files

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pattern-matching, difflib

I have two files and I am trying to print unique sentences between both files. For this I am using difflib in python.

```
text ='Physics is one of the oldest academic disciplines. Perhaps the oldest through its inclusion of astronomy. Over the last two millennia. Physics was a part of natural philosophy along with chemistry.'
text1 ='Physics is one of the oldest academic disciplines. Physics was a part of natural philosophy along with chemistry. Quantum chemistry is a branch of chemistry.'
import difflib

differ = difflib.Differ()
diff = differ.compare(text,text1)
print '\n'.join(diff)
```

and its not giving me desired output. Its giving me like this.

```
  P
  h
  y
  s
  i
  c
  s

  i
  s

  o
  n
  e

  o
  f

  t
  h
  e
```

My desired output is just unique sentences between both files.

> text = Perhaps the oldest through its inclusion of astronomy. Over the
>   last two millennia.
>
> text1 = Quantum chemistry is a branch of chemistry.

Also it seems like difflib.Differ is going line by line not by sentences. Any suggestion please. How I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, indeed, Differ().compare() compares lines, not sentences.

Second, it actually compares sequences, such as lists of strings. However, you pass two strings, not two lists of strings. Since a string is also a sequence (of characters), Differ().compare() in your case compares the individual characters.

If you want to compare files by sentences, you must prepare two lists of sentences. You can use nltk.sent_tokenize(text) to split a string into sentences.

```
diff = differ.compare(nltk.sent_tokenize(text),nltk.sent_tokenize(text1))
print('\n'.join(diff))
#  Physics is one of the oldest academic disciplines.
#- Perhaps the oldest through its inclusion of astronomy.
#- Over the last two millennia.
#  Physics was a part of natural philosophy along with chemistry.
#+ Quantum chemistry is a branch of chemistry.
```

Comment: Thank you DYZ. Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I have one more question to you. Let's say we have one string "I am boy" and other one is "I am, boy". There is a (,) after am. differ.compare says they both are unique not similar because of (,). How we can consider that case here. I am its related to nltk. But can I handle this case here.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the difflib package (but I'm glad to learn about it!) but you can also strip out any punctuation manually before running your text through the diff. Check out strip() for your strings before splitting on period.

Comment: I suggest that you use a word tokenizer from nltk to extract words: `" ".join(w for w in nltk.word_tokenize('I am, boy') if w.isalpha())`. Or you can use regular expressions to extract words.

Answer (score 2):

As DZinoviev stated above, you are passing strings into a function that expects lists. You don't need to use NLTK, instead you can just turn your strings into lists of sentences by splitting on the period.

```
import difflib

text1 ="""Physics is one of the oldest academic disciplines. Perhaps the oldest through its inclusion of astronomy. Over the last two millennia. Physics was a part of natural philosophy along with chemistry."""
text2 ="""Physics is one of the oldest academic disciplines. Physics was a part of natural philosophy along with chemistry. Quantum chemistry is a branch of chemistry."""

list1 = list(text1.split("."))
list2 = list(text2.split("."))

differ = difflib.Differ()
diff = differ.compare(list1,list2)
print "\n".join(diff)
```

Comment: Thank you SummerEla

Comment: There may be other punctuation signs separating sentences, such as !, ?, ..., etc.